# Best texts on cash usage and share buybacks in companies

Tags: reference-request, stock-market, corporate-finance, value, soft-question

What would be a good reference for how companies utilise their cash to conduct share buybacks. I am trying to understand how share buybacks affect the valuation of a company.

Comment: I am interested to know too...